# Window stops moving while being dragged

Tags: mouse

While I drag a window, the window will often gain freedom from the mouse and stop. Sometimes the mouse will start to accidentally highlight text in that window instead. It seems like the mouse will randomly hiccup and lose its grasp. This issue was experienced with multiple mice.

Is this a known issue?